# I can log into MySQL Docker Container from CLI but my Python (FastAPI) app cannot connect to the server

Tags: python, mysql, docker, fastapi

I have two containers one for a FastAPI app and another for MySQL database. There are no errors when I run `docker-compose build`. I can run `docker exec <mysql_container name> mysql -u user -p` and get into MySQL but the app refuses to connect.

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    api_server:
        container_name: api_server
        build:
            context: ./backend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./backend/:/backend/
        command: uvicorn app.api.server:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
        env_file:
            - ./backend/.env
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        depends_on: 
            - mysql_database
    mysql_database:
        container_name: mysql_database
        image: mysql:latest
        volumes:
            - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
        env_file:
            - ./backend/.env
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        ports: 
            - 3307:3306
volumes: 
    mysql_data:
```

the remaining environment variables are inside my .env file:

```
###> database configuration ###
MYSQL_USER=user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_SERVER=mysql_database
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database
###< database configuration ###

###> other variables ###
###< other variables ###
```

and I connect my app with a config.py where I read my env variables and a tasks.py file where I connect and disconnect to the DB, but I don't think the problem is here since I can connect the app to any existent MySQL database outside my docker container...

```
# the config.py file
from typing import cast
from databases import DatabaseURL
from starlette.config import Config
from starlette.datastructures import Secret

config = Config(".env")

VERSION = "0.1.0"
API_PREFIX = "/api"
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN = config("CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN", cast=str, default="*")

SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY", cast=Secret, default="CHANGEME")

MYSQL_USER = config("MYSQL_USER", cast=str)
MYSQL_PASSWORD = config("MYSQL_PASSWORD", cast=Secret)
MYSQL_SERVER = config("MYSQL_SERVER", cast=str, default="localhost")
MYSQL_PORT = config("MYSQL_PORT", cast=str, default="3306")
MYSQL_DATABASE = config("MYSQL_DATABASE", cast=str)

DATABASE_URL = config(
    "DATABASE_URL",
    cast=DatabaseURL,
    default=f"mysql://{MYSQL_USER}:{MYSQL_PASSWORD}@{MYSQL_SERVER}:{MYSQL_PORT}/{MYSQL_DATABASE}"
)
# alembic will not accept url without pymysql driver
MIGRATIONS_URL = config(
    "DATABASE_URL",
    cast=DatabaseURL,
    default=f"mysql+pymysql://{MYSQL_USER}:{MYSQL_PASSWORD}@{MYSQL_SERVER}:{MYSQL_PORT}/{MYSQL_DATABASE}"
)
```

```
# the tasks.py file
import os
from fastapi import FastAPI
from databases import Database
from app.core.config import DATABASE_URL
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def connect_to_db(app: FastAPI) -> None:
    DB_URL = f"{DATABASE_URL}_test" if os.environ.get("TESTING") else DATABASE_URL 
    database = Database(DB_URL, min_size=2, max_size=10)

    try:
        await database.connect()
        app.state._db = database
    except Exception as e:
        logger.warn("--- DB CONNECTION ERROR ---")
        logger.warn(e)
        logger.warn("--- DB CONNECTION ERROR ---")


async def close_db_connection(app: FastAPI) -> None:
    try:
        await app.state._db.disconnect()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.warn("--- DB DISCONNECT ERROR ---")
        logger.warn(e)
        logger.warn("--- DB DISCONNECT ERROR ---")
```

Edit: here's the output when I run `docker-compose build`:

```
Starting mysql_database ... done
Starting api_server     ... done
Attaching to mysql_database, api_server
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09 23:32:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.25-1debian10 started.
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09 23:32:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09 23:32:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.25-1debian10 started.
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09T23:32:44.082892Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25) starting as process 1
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09T23:32:44.091693Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09T23:32:44.263990Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09T23:32:44.377132Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/my
sqlx.sock
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09T23:32:44.479897Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09T23:32:44.480103Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for
this channel.
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09T23:32:44.485195Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessib
le to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_database    | 2021-06-09T23:32:44.511875Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.25'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysql
d.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
api_server        | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
api_server        | INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using statreload
api_server        | INFO:     Started server process [9]
api_server        | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
api_server        | --- DB CONNECTION ERROR ---
api_server        | (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql_database'")
api_server        | --- DB CONNECTION ERROR ---
api_server        | INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

Btw I'm learning to use FastAPI with Docker using [this set of tutorials](https://www.jeffastor.com/blog/pairing-a-postgresql-db-with-your-dockerized-fastapi-app) and while it's using Postgres, I'm trying to use MySQL on my own so I can understand better the topics.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I noticed in the log, it shows the binding port to be 33060.  Is this a copy and paste error or is there a setting that specifies 33060?   My yml is a bit rusty, so also curious about the port ```- 3307:3306```  line.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I thought the same and searched for that number in my project dir but there was no port 33060 so I think it has nothing to do with my problem. The `port - 3307:3306` line says that the mysql container 3306 port will be forwarded to the 3307 in my machine. However the API service should connect to the 3306 port as [this response says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60170889/cannot-connect-to-mysql-python-mysql-connector-when-in-docker-container)